# Running a custom formula for conditional formatting in google sheets only formats the first cell in the "apply to range"

Tags: regex, google-sheets, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

Help!

I am using the formula: `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Y",K6))` as a custom formula to conditionally format a range of cells. It works when K6 has a "Y" in it but only for the first cell in the apply to range.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=REGEXMATCH(K6, "Y")
```

for range K6:K

Comment: Unfortunately that has the same result. I am setting it for a range of cells in a row. ie: C6:I6. When K6 is populated with a "Y" only C6 is conditionally formatted. Thanks though!

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output?

Comment: =$k6="Y" It works! Thanks for the help, I was making it too complicated.